# fetching values from database which are not from specific month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch hotel id, hotel name and hotel type of hotels which has not taken any orders in the month of 'MAY 19' but i am not getting proper output what is wrong in my query?

```
select hotel_details.hotel_id,hotel_name,hotel_type 
from hotel_details inner join orders on hotel_details.hotel_id=orders.hotel_id 
where Month(order_date) between 1 and 4 or Month(order_date) between 6 and 12 
order by hotel_id;
```

[image: My table structure]

Comment: can you show sample data and expected result please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, using `NOT EXISTS` to check if there is any order for the hotel in May 2019:

```
SELECT hotel_id, hotel_name, hotel_type 
FROM hotel_details 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM orders 
  WHERE hotel_id = hotel_details.hotel_id 
    AND MONTH(order_date) = 5 
    AND YEAR(order_date) = 2019
)
```

The sub-query on `EXISTS` checks if the `hotel_id` is available in orders on May 2019. Using `NOT` in front of `EXISTS` filters all hotels which have no order in May 2019. The sub-query is connected to the outer part of the query with `hotel_id = hotel_details.hotel_id`.

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes

Comment: I am not getting why you used select 1?

Comment: You can also use a column or any other value. The `EXISTS` is true in case the select returns rows. If the select doesn't return rows the exists is false.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a standard, if somewhat old-fashioned approach...
(I've assumed a column name on the orders table, but you can change it to any non-nullable orders column, if it's wrong)

```
SELECT d.hotel_id
     , d.hotel_name
     , d.hotel_type 
  FROM hotel_details d
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o 
    ON d.hotel_id = o.hotel_id 
   AND d.order_date >= '2019-05-01' 
   AND d.order_date < '2019-06-01'
 WHERE o.id IS NULL
 ORDER 
    BY d.hotel_id;
```

For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HOTEL_ID,HOTEL_NAME,HOTEL_TYPE FROM HOTEL_DETAILS
WHERE HOTEL_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT HOTEL_ID FROM ORDERS
WHERE MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 5)
ORDER BY HOTEL_ID ASC;
```

Here in the below sub query we are trying to obtain the `HOTEL_ID`(s) which have placed order in the month of May using the `MONTH` function. In outer query which receives a list of `HOTEL_ID`(s) which have an ordered in the month of may. Now the `NOT IN` condition omits the `HOTEL_ID` present in the list and displays the other `HOTEL_ID` which have not ordered in the month of May.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT h.hotel_id, 
                h.hotel_name, 
                h.hotel_type 
FROM   hotel_details h 
WHERE  h.hotel_id NOT IN (SELECT od.hotel_id 
                          FROM   orders od 
                          WHERE  ( h.hotel_id = od.hotel_id 
                                   AND Month(order_date) = 05 ) 
                          GROUP  BY h.hotel_id 
                          ORDER  BY h.hotel_id ASC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Nested Queries:

```
SELECT hotel_id, hotel_name, hotel_type
FROM hotel_details
WHERE hotel_id  NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id
        FROM orders
        WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-31'
        )
ORDER BY hotel_id;
```

Explanation :

- In the Inner Query, we are selecting distinct hotel IDs from the order table with orders between May 1 and May 31.
- Once we have list of hotel IDs, in the outer query we can display the required columns of the hotel table which have IDs not in the list.